# Returning array of dynamically allocated wchar_t* from a function

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, memory-management

I have a function whose signature is as follows:

```
GetCustomers( wchar_t** Name,int *count);
```

In main method: Call to customer looks like this:

```
GetCustomers( Name,&count);
```

The body of the function is as follows: (since count of customers is unknown , I am trying to allocate meomry dynamically)

```
GetCustomers( wchar_t** Name,int *count)
{
    //Logic to get customer count : Stored in int  myCustomersCount
    Names = new wchar_t*[myCustomersCount];

    for (int i=0; i < myCustomersCount; i++ )     
    {
        Names[i] = new wchar_t;
    }

    //Logic to get customer names in  wchar_t* strName = "Name1";
    Names[0] = strName;
    *count = myCustomersCount;
}
```

I would think that this implementation  would allow array Name to be passed back correctly to the Main() function with memory allocation on heap but it seems not to work. What is wrong here? myCustomersCount seems to be correct in caller.

PS: The code compile and executes but array received in Main is garbage.

Comment: You should be using `std::vector` and/or `std::wstring`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "but it seems not to work" are you having compilation issues; are you segfaulting or is Name just not valid?  Where is strName defined?  It is possible that strName is a local var in GetCustomers which could cause it to be incorrect when you return to the caller.

Comment: I am not getting the name array in caller: Compiles and runs fine. strName comes from call to another function ...I get a valid pointer back so I am assuming it is valid? I just tried creating a copy of that pointer in new tempStrName and returning that to caller in aforementioned array: in VS2008 debugger I see <undefined value>.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be thinking in terms of C, not really C++. I'd use something like:

```
std::vector<std::string> GetCustomers();
```

or (probably preferred):

```
template <class outIt>
void GetCustomers(outIt output_iterator);
```

The latter you'd use something like:

```
std::vector<std::wstring> customers;

GetCustomers(std::back_inserter(customers));
```

The third obvious possibility would be to just equip your `customers` class with a `begin()` and `end()` member functions that return iterators to the customers data.

Edit2: Here's some tested demo code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>

void GetCustomers(wchar_t ***names, int *count) { 
    static wchar_t *myCustomers[] = { 
        L"You",
        L"Him",
        L"Her"
    };
    int myCustomersCount = 3;
    wchar_t **temp = new wchar_t *[myCustomersCount];

    *count = myCustomersCount;
    for (int i=0; i<myCustomersCount; i++) {
        temp[i] = new wchar_t[wcslen(myCustomers[i])+1];
        wcscpy(temp[i], myCustomers[i]);
    }
    *names = temp;
}

int main() { 
    wchar_t **customers;
    int count;

    GetCustomers(&customers, &count);

    for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
        printf("%S\n", customers[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Jerry: This is a very good answer, but I somehow get the feeling that the OP is still learning the C subset of C++. If that is the case, he must learn to deal manually with low-level tasks such as memory allocation, and only then he will be able to learn powerful abstractions such as strings and vectors.

Comment: @Eduardo: What are you smoking? It's beneficial for programmers to ditch the C subset immediately.

Comment: @Eduardo Leon: I can't agree. vector and string should come first. Many people will never need to learn about completely manual management at all. Those who do can still learn it later, not first.

Comment: Some of us learned the programming the JAVA and C# way but have to deal with legacy code now and then...it is never too late to learn anything and ditching the C subset would mean ditching legacy application. Not always an option.

Comment: Jerry indeed has a good answer but somehow it won't work for me in this particular case.

Comment: @Jerry, @DeadMG: It seems like the OP is a student, and the lecturers (or whoever design the C++ course he is taking) have already decided to teach the C subset. I know it is not a good decision, but that is not something we can deal with directly. In the meanwhile, the OP needs a solution.

Comment: @Ed: This is a solution. @lazy: Why isn't this solution going to work? (What is "somehow"?)

Comment: GMan, If I could change the signature of my function, I would not post this question here...is there a reason people are changing signatures?

Comment: Although I am going  to try this now and if it works, mark this as an answer.

Comment: @lazynomore: yes -- because the signature you've given *won't work* for what you've asked it to do.

Comment: I do see the folly of my ways :) Thanks everyone. Still trying to see if this will work.

Comment: For some reasons, why is Temp[i] ( 0 < i <customerCount ) returning one customer name in main function? In debugger (for this line wcscpy(temp[i], myCustomers[i])) , the value  myCustomers[i] changes but temp[i] keeps returning first customer name.

Comment: @lazynomore: I'm not sure what problem you're encountering. I've added enough more to test/demonstrate the code, and at least for me it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure what you're trying to do here; from what I understand about your code; you're trying to store some strings into an array of an array of character pointers.

```
GetCustomers(wchar_t **Name, int *count) {
   Name = new wchar_t*[myCustomersCount];
   for(int i = 0; i < myCustomersCount; i++) {
     /* Get your customer name and store into strName */
     Name[i] = strName;
   }
   *count = myCustomersCount;
}
```

Comment: Still won't work because the code assumes changes to the local copy of the `Name` parameter will affect the actual object the caller is using. `Name = new wchar_t*[myCustomersCount];` doesn't do anything to the actual object that the caller is using.

Answer (score 0):

In main, presumably you've got something like this

```
wchar_t *Name = NULL;
```

and then you say

```
GetCustomers( Name,&count);
```

This passes Name by value, but you want to pass it by reference:

```
GetCustomers( &Name,&count);
```

And presumably it's just a typo, but your parameter name is Name (singular) but you refer to it as Names (plural) in the function:

```
GetCustomers( wchar_t** Name,int *count)
{
    //Logic to get customer count : Stored in int  myCustomersCount
    Names = new wchar_t*[myCustomersCount];
```

In any case, you want to assign to where Name is pointing, not to itself:

```
*Names = new wchar_t*[myCustomersCount];
```

Then for each element in Names you allocate one character, but then overwrite the first one with strName. The allocation is unnecessary (and in fact is a memory leak), and you should assign from strName to each element within the loop, as Suroot's answer does.

Comment: Line  "*Names = new wchar_t*[myCustomersCount];" would throw following compilation error:  cannot convert from 'wchar_t **' to 'wchar_t *'

Comment: Yes, I know. But I didn't want to complicate things any more than they already are, so I thought I'd leave that until you'd fixed up all the other problems. The correct thing is to change the parameter from `wchar_t**` to `wchar_t***` (basically, a pointer to an array of strings) but I note in your comment on another answer that you can't change the signature. In that case you can use a cast: `*Names = (wchar_t*)new wchar_t*[xxx]`. You should avoid casts when you can, but since you know it's an array of wchar_t* then the pointer to the array is the same as the pointer to its first element.

Comment: Result of the cast: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in XXX.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't passed the address of your variable from main. Should be something like this: `wchar_t *names = NULL; int count; GetCustomers(&names,&count);`

Comment: I did pass address but remember names is initialized to null in main.

Comment: It seems that you're tied up in a knot. Apart from the problems within your function, you may have problems in main() and in the function that gives you the names. You really need a coherent memory management strategy, and for that you need to consider the entire environment. For example, if you use a cast like I suggest then you have to be sure that main() deletes the array correctly. This is why you should try to avoid casts - they basically tell the compiler that you're doing something dodgy but you know what you're doing and you'll ensure that it all works out OK in the end.

Answer (score 0):

2 definite issue and 1 potential issue with your code. The main issue causing your problem first: `Name` itself is passed by value. That means when you you assign to it in the very first line of your function when you `new` the memory, you're assigning to the copy, not the original! You have three options: 1) keep the double pointer, make the caller responsible for allocating the memory, and add a third parameter for number of names that the array can hold (recommended) or 2) make Name a triple pointer (`wchar_t*** Name`) and then you can assign to it by dereferencing it: `*Name = new wchar_t*[myCustomersCount];` or 3) just return the `wchar_t**` since you don't use the passed value for anything.

Then another definite issue: when you allocate memory for each name, you need to use the `new[]` operator there as well because otherwise you're only allocating room for a single `wchar_t`.

Finally, the potential issue. You don't show how exactly this code is getting each customer name. But if `strName` points to memory that is getting reused for each customer name as you put them all in your array, you're going to have to `wstrcpy` each name into the array. If it doesn't, then you don't need to allocate memory for each `Names[i]` as you can just store the result right into `Names[i]`.

A final note: just from looking at this code it seems like you're going to have lots of problems with memory management as it seems *very* unclear who is responsible for allocating and deallocating memory which is likely going to lead to memory leaks. Try your best to keep the responsibility for allocating and deallocating the memory in the same location and you'll reduce lots of potential headaches -- have callers allocate the memory before they call the function and have the caller deallocate the memory when they're done with it.

```
/* changed */
wchar_t** GetCustomers( int *count)
{
    //Logic to get customer count : Stored in int  myCustomersCount
    wchar_t **Names = new wchar_t*[myCustomersCount];

    for (int i=0; i < myCustomersCount; i++ )     
    {
                              /* changed */
        Names[i] = new wchar_t[MAX_NAME_SIZE];
    }

    //Logic to get customer names in  wchar_t* strName = "Name1";
    Names[0] = strName; /* possible wstrcpy needed here? */
    *count = myCustomersCount;

    /* changed */
    return Names;
}
```

**Edit**
If you *really* **absolutely** can't change the function signature, the only solution I can think of is to flatten your array and use C memory functions (you could also just use a long series of `new`s and `delete`s, but why not use `realloc` when this is what it's made for and you're managing memory without using other C++ features like the STL anyways?):

```
GetCustomers( wchar_t **Names, int *count)
{
    //Logic to get customer count : Stored in int  myCustomersCount
    size_t names_size = 0;

    for (int i=0; i < myCustomersCount; i++ )     
    {
        strName = ???; // whatever you use to get the next name

        size_t old_names_size = names_size;
        names_size += (wstrlen(strName) + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t); //+1 for NULL
        *Names = realloc(*Names, names_size);

        if (!*Names) {
            // Memory allocation failed, log it, abort, do whatever
        }

        wstrcpy(Names[old_names_size], strName);
    }
    *count = myCustomersCount;
}
```

Note that this assumes that `Name` has already been initialized and points to memory where you can store a `wchar_t*`, just like the original version assumed `count` has been initialized and points to memory where you can store an `int`.

Comment: Sorry, you have the changed the signature of my function: something I can not do! Thanks anyways.

Comment: @lazynomore Well what can you do then?

Comment: I was hoping that I can get array back with original function signature.

Comment: @lazynomore As I mentioned above, you can repeatedly call `new` and `delete`, but you'll also have to copy the old contents to the new one each time which will be very inefficient. Besides, this code is already handling memory C-style anyways, so using `realloc` isn't exactly a break in the style of the code either.

Comment: This line :  *accountNames = ( wchar_t*)realloc(*accountNames, names_size); threw this exception: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in XXX.exe Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: "Note that this assumes that `Name` has already been initialized and points to memory where you can store a `wchar_t*`." When you call `GetCustomers`, `Names` cannot be NULL, just like `count` cannot be NULL. You have to pass a pointer to a valid region of memory that can hold an address, just like you do for `count` (except `*count` holds an integer instead of an address).

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd make a fresh start in a new answer.

Here's a simple program that does what I think you're trying to do, with the constraint that the signature of GetCustomers must not be altered.

```
void GetCustomers(wchar_t** Names,int *count)
{
    // Allocate the array of names
    wchar_t **ar = new wchar_t*[3];
    // Allocate space for each name in the array
    ar[0] = new wchar_t[10];
    ar[1] = new wchar_t[10];
    ar[2] = new wchar_t[10];
    // Fill in the names
    wcscpy(ar[0],L"joe");
    wcscpy(ar[1],L"jim");
    wcscpy(ar[2],L"bob");
    // Return the array through the bad GetCustomers signature
    *Names = (wchar_t*)ar;
    *count = 3;
}

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    // names is an array of strings
    wchar_t **names = NULL;
    int count;
    // Squeeze names into the dodgy GetCustomers signature
    GetCustomers((wchar_t**)&names,&count);

    // Delete each name
    for(size_t x = 0; x < count; ++x)
        delete[] names[x];
    // Delete the array
    delete[] names;

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I've matched the cast inside the function with another one in main. This way we keep everything as it should be, except for that pesky GetCustomers signature.

Does this help?

Comment: This is a good solution...the only downside I see here is that names can't be more than 10 chars long. Thanks!

Comment: This is just a demo to show how to get past the troublesome GetCustomers signature. I think you already have code for getting the names and adding them to the array, so use that instead of my sample code.